# In a field F , 0 multiplied by any element is still in the field still in field, how to prove it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I read the following definition of a field;

$\mbox{ A field}\  \mathcal{F}\ \mbox{is a set}\ \mathcal{F}\ \mbox{ with two operations}\ + \ \mbox{and}\ \cdot ,\ \mbox{s.t}$

$$ < \mathcal{F},\ +>\ \mbox{is a commutative group},$$

$$<\mathcal{F}/\{0\},\ \cdot>\ \mbox{is a commutative group},$$

$$a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b + a\cdot c,$$

$$(b+c)\cdot a = b\cdot a + c \cdot a.$$

Based on these assumptions how can I prove that $\forall a\in\mathcal{F}, \ a\cdot0\in \mathcal{F}$.

Note, you can not assume that $a\cdot 0 = 0$ or $0\cdot a \in\mathcal{F}$.

One possible solution is

\begin{eqnarray}
0a &=& 0a+0\nonumber\\
&=& 0a +a + - a\nonumber\\
&=& 0a + 1a +-a\nonumber\\
&=&(0+1)a+-a\\
&=& 1a+-a\nonumber\\
&=& a-a\nonumber\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
But again in equation $4$, I am taking out $a$ common from $0a+1a$ assuming that $0a\in\mathcal{F}$, which cant be done.

Comment: This is part of the definition of "operation".  We assume $\cdot$ is an operation on $\mathcal F$.  Therefore $a\cdot 0 \in \mathcal F$.  Of course we need to know this before we can prove $a\cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: Agree with previous comment: the relevant part of the definition is "a set $\mathcal{F}$ with two operations ${+}$ and ${\cdot}$".

Comment: $a, 0\in \mathcal{F}$  then $a\cdot 0\in\mathcal{F}$ Nothing to prove. One easy but interesting question would be to show $a\cdot 0=0$ .

Comment: @LostinSpace; $a,0\in\mathcal{F}$ doesn't mean $a\cdot 0 \in \mathcal{F}$. Look at the definition of a field that I just gave. It doesn't answer $a\cdot 0\in \mathcal{F}$

Comment: $\cdot$ is a binary operation. Ot follows from definition

Comment: I would like to be the fourth person to say in the comments that it is part of the definition of a (binary) operation on a set.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit subtle, but when we say $\cdot$ is a (binary) operation on $\mathcal{F}$, we mean that it defines a map $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ by definition.